# Choosing the underline color for an Emphasis-Underline animation in Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'd like for one the words in my slide to be highlighted at some point in the presentation, so I've added an "Underline" animation for it from the Emphasis group.

However, choosing the color used for this underline isn't among the available options for that animation type (screenshot below). The default color is used, which in this case isn't suitable.
[image]

My only work around has been to instead add a line that appears under that word and functions as an underline. However if anyone can suggest a less hacky workaround, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the text that you want to be underlined

[image]

2. In the "Home" tab under the "Font" section, click on the little arrow in the bottom right corner

[image]

3. In the new dialog window, select an underline style and an underline color and confirm your choice with "OK". This new underline color is now saved with the paragraph.

[image]

4. Deactivate the underline again by simply click on the corresponding button  in the "Home" tab

[image]

5. If you now apply the underline animation to the text, it will have the color that you've previously set

Comment: Great work around thank you. I love how much hidden power and flexibility there is in Powerpoint. Very underrated piece of software :)